# comparing == operator for (struct &a, struct &b) vs (const struct &a, const struct &b)

Tags: c++, struct, constants, comparator

I have defined a struct class called `Point` in my header file as follows -

```
namespace global_planner {
    class GlobalPlanner : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner {
        struct Point {
            __uint32_t x, y; 
            bool operator==(const Point &p1 ) {
                return ((p1.x == x) && (p1.y == y));  
            }
            bool operator<(const Point &p1 ) const {
                return ((p1.x < x) || (p1.x == x && p1.y < y) ) ; 
            }   
        };
    public:
        ///
    private: 
        ////               
    };
    
};
```

In my source file (named `global_planner.cpp`), I have a function named `generate_straight_path` defined as follows -

```
bool GlobalPlanner::generate_straight_path(const Point &p1, const Point &p2){        
    if(costmap_ros_->getCost(p1.x, p1.y) == costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE) {
        cout << "Point p1 is on obstacle!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(costmap_ros_->getCost(p2.x, p2.y) == costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE) {
        cout << "Point p2 is on obstacle!" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(p1 == p2) {return 1;}
    if(p1.x == p2.x){}
    if(p1.y == p2.y){}
  }
```

When I compile global_planner.cpp, I am getting the following error -

```
/home/skpro19/catkin_ws/src/my_global_planner/src/global_planner.cpp: In member function ‘bool global_planner::GlobalPlanner::generate_straight_path(const global_planner::GlobalPlanner::Point&, const global_planner::GlobalPlanner::Point&)’:
/home/skpro19/catkin_ws/src/my_global_planner/src/global_planner.cpp:150:11: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const global_planner::GlobalPlanner::Point’ and ‘const global_planner::GlobalPlanner::Point’)
     if(p1 == p2) {return 1;}
```

The error disappears if I change the definition of `generate_straight_path` from `generate_straight_path(const Point &p1, const Point &p2)` to `generate_straight_path(Point &p1, Point &p2)`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7):

Your equality operator overload is a member function, but not marked `const`:

```
 bool operator==(const Point &p1 ) { return ((p1.x == x) && (p1.y == y)); }
```

When you turn it into a `const` member function, this should work as expected:

```
bool operator==(const Point &p1 ) const { return ((p1.x == x) && (p1.y == y)); }
```

It's a bit blurry through the operator, but when you look at it this way:

```
bool GlobalPlanner::generate_straight_path(const Point &p1, const Point &p2){
    // ...

    if (p1.operator==(p2)) /* ... */ ;
}
```

which is the more verbose way to call an member operator overload, you can see that this `operator==` must be `const` because the function argument `const Point& p1` is `const` itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is only by coincidence that you can fix it by removing a `const`. In fact you need to add one here:

```
bool operator==(const Point &p1 ) const {   return ((p1.x == x) && (p1.y == y));  }   
                                 // ^^^
```

Otherwise you can only call `operator==` with a non-const left hand operand.